# count occurrences in preg_replace regex

Tags: php

I know that with I can find of occurrences with preg_match_all 
i.e.

```
<?php
$text = 'here is JUICE. it is good JUICE...';
$counted    = preg_match_all('/JUICE/',$text,$empt);
echo $counted;
?>
```

but how can I count occurrences with preg_replace?

Comment: You can read [the manual](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), there is an optional 5th parameter `$count`, which will be set to the number of replacements performed:

```
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject, -1, $count)
```

The 4th parameter is the `$limit` on the number of replacements. `-1` means no limit.

Comment: Not quite right, you forgot the `$limit` parameter ;)